# Combining two $.each functions

Tags: jquery, json

I have a function that needs to run on a two json arrays.When i repeat the function for each of the arrays it works fine.But definitely not the right way to write the code.I need to combine the $.each for json arrays which am stuck at.

Here`s my function:

```
$(function() {
   $.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
       $.each(data.Full_Talktime, function(index, plan) {


            var  tblPara = $('<p class="col1">').html("<b>Talktime</b><br>");
            var  tblValidity = $('<p class="col2">').html("<b>Validity</b><br>");
            var  tblPrice = $('<p class="col3">');
            var  tblDescription = $('<p class="row2">').html("<b>Description</b><br>");
            var  endline =$('<div class="end">');
            tblPara.append('<div class="para">' + plan.Talktime + '</div>');
            tblValidity.append('<div class="para">' + plan.Validity + '</div>');
            tblPrice.append('<div class="col3para">' + plan.Price + '</div>');
            tblDescription.append('<div class="para">' + plan.Description + '</div>');
    console.log(plan);

           $(".content").append(tblPara).append(tblValidity).append(tblPrice).append(tblDescription).append(endline);

     });
     $.each(data.Special_Recharge, function(index, plan) {


            var  tblPara = $('<p class="col1">').html("<b>Talktime</b><br>");
            var  tblValidity = $('<p class="col2">').html("<b>Validity</b><br>");
            var  tblPrice = $('<p class="col3">');
            var  tblDescription = $('<p class="row2">').html("<b>Description</b><br>");
            var  endline =$('<div class="end">');
            tblPara.append('<div class="para">' + plan.Talktime + '</div>');
            tblValidity.append('<div class="para">' + plan.Validity + '</div>');
            tblPrice.append('<div class="col3para">' + plan.Price + '</div>');
            tblDescription.append('<div class="para">' + plan.Description + '</div>');
    console.log(plan);

               $(".content").append(tblPara).append(tblValidity).append(tblPrice).append(tblDescription).append(endline);

     });
   });
});
```

Here`s my json:

```
{
    "Ai": [
    {"Full_Talktime":[
{"Talktime":"300", "Validity":"Lifetime","Price":"Rs 300", "Description":"200 full talktime"}, 
{"Talktime":"300", "Validity":"Lifetime","Price":"Rs 300", "Description":"200 full talktime"},
{"Talktime":"300", "Validity":"Lifetime","Price":"Rs 300", "Description":"200 full talktime"},
{"Talktime":"300", "Validity":"Lifetime","Price":"Rs 300", "Description":"200 full talktime"},
{"Talktime":"300", "Validity":"Lifetime","Price":"Rs 300", "Description":"200 full talktime"},
{"Talktime":"300", "Validity":"Lifetime","Price":"Rs 300", "Description":"200 full talktime"},
{"Talktime":"300", "Validity":"Lifetime","Price":"Rs 300", "Description":"200 full talktime"}
],
"Special_Recharge":[
{"Talktime":"300", "Validity":"Lifetime","Price":"Rs 3000", "Description":"200 full talktime"}, 
{"Talktime":"300", "Validity":"Lifetime","Price":"Rs 3000", "Description":"200 full talktime"},
{"Talktime":"300", "Validity":"Lifetime","Price":"Rs 3000", "Description":"200 full talktime"},
{"Talktime":"300", "Validity":"Lifetime","Price":"Rs 300", "Description":"200 full talktime"},
{"Talktime":"300", "Validity":"Lifetime","Price":"Rs 300", "Description":"200 full talktime"},
{"Talktime":"300", "Validity":"Lifetime","Price":"Rs 300", "Description":"200 full talktime"},
{"Talktime":"300", "Validity":"Lifetime","Price":"Rs 300", "Description":"200 full talktime"}
]
}
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    $.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
        $.each(data.AI, function(index, plan) {
            $.each( plan,function(i,obj) {
                   // i will be Full_Talktime,Special_Recharge iteratively..
                   var recharge_instance = obj //obj will be the object and u can access like obj.Talktime;
                  // print stuff out here...
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are just trying to cut down on the duplicate code, you could using a function reference in both `each`'s:

```
$.each(data.Full_Talktime, printPlan);
$.each(data.Special_Recharge, printPlan);

function printPlan(index, plan) {
    var  tblPara = $('<p class="col1">').html("<b>Talktime</b><br>");
    var  tblValidity = $('<p class="col2">').html("<b>Validity</b><br>");
    var  tblPrice = $('<p class="col3">');
    var  tblDescription = $('<p class="row2">').html("<b>Description</b><br>");
    var  endline =$('<div class="end">');
    tblPara.append('<div class="para">' + plan.Talktime + '</div>');
    tblValidity.append('<div class="para">' + plan.Validity + '</div>');
    tblPrice.append('<div class="col3para">' + plan.Price + '</div>');
    tblDescription.append('<div class="para">' + plan.Description + '</div>');
    console.log(plan);
    $(".content").append(tblPara).append(tblValidity).append(tblPrice).append(tblDescription).append(endline);
});
```